# Azure website fails to call SharePoint CSOM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2013, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-online

My provider-hosted (MVC) app for SharePoint 2013 is deployed to Azure website. However once it calls SharePoint CSOM it fails with unexpected error.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What fails, what's the exact error message, what trouble shooting steps have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you make a request directly to web site, using a url (e.g. "xxx.azurewebsites.net") because in your "Index" ActionMethod is marked with:

> [SharePointContextFilter]

If you want access to your web site outside from Sharepoint, you can have in your Provider App, two controllers. One configured how ClientWebPart for access inside from Sharepoint and other for external access.